# How to generate a continuous random variable with the density $f(x) = 1.5x^2, -1 < x < 1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $U$ be a Standard Uniform random variable. Show all the steps required to generate a continuous random variable with the density $f(x) = 1.5x^2$, $-1 < x < 1$.

I'm not looking for exact answers as much as proper solutions for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote new random variable as **V** and its distribution function as **F**(x). Then:

**F**(x)=(x^3+1)/2=**G**( **G`** (**F**(x) ) )=**G**( (x^3+1)/2 )=**P**( **U** <= (x^3+1)/2 ) =**P**( 2U-1 <= x^3 )=**P**( (2U-1)^(1/3) <= x ).
So, (2*U-1)^(1/3) is that random variable you need.

(As **G`**(x) I denote inverse function for **G**(x). G(x) is distribution function for U)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You want to solve $F(X) = U$, where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: So would I just integrate 1.5x^2 between -1 and 1 for the answer?

Comment: No, integrate between $-1$ and $X$.